# Coordenadas GPS a mapa estático C# +Unity

Tags: c#, unity, gps

Estoy intentando realizar un pequeño proyecto en el que, dentro de un plano de 512 x 512 tengo que posicionar un marcador en las coordenadas REALES del gps.

La cuestión es la siguiente:
-La imagen es estatica
-El marcador se mueve dentro de las coordenadas del objeto (plano antes mencionado).

¿Cómo puedo transformar la lectura de latitud y longitud en una posición lo más exacta posible? He probado un par de formulas para intentar calcular la difrencia entre los 4 puntos respecto al punto 0,0 pero algo estoy haciendo mal y se me acaba el tiempo. Un saludo y muchas gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDsfY.png)

Comment: Pero la geolocalizacion, aplica sobre el mapa del mundo, no sobre una imagen, por eso es "geo". No aplica sobre una posicion 0,0. Puede usar servicio de Google Map, Bing Maps o Azure Maps https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/azure-maps/ pero debe aplicar sobre un mapa del planeta

Comment: Si pones la localizacion 0,0 en google maps obtendras un lugar sobre el Ecuador, cercado a Africa, pero en el oceano https://www.google.com/maps/place/0°00'00.0"N+0°00'00.0"E/ . Deberias ubicar en el planeta donde es esa imagen y despues con las coordenadas calcular

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Pero necesito ver el código de lo que has intentado. Según mi entender, tienes una imagen estática en un cuadro 512x512, tienes las coordenadas (lat, long) de los 4 puntos que corresponden a dicho cuadro, tienes un punto dentro de esas coordenadas y quieres posicionarlo (mapearlo) sobre la imagen 512x512 lo más exacto posible. Si me equivoco me corriges.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Es exactamente eso, sí. Bueno, el código como está ahora está muy sucio. Pero simplemente he intentado coger la latitud del GPS restarla por la "latitud minima" que se encuentra dentro de la imagen (lo que vendría a ser la esquina inferior izqueirda, si no me equivoco). Eso dividido por la diferencia entre latitud máxima y latitud mínima. Con la Longitus, pues igual... ya he llegado al punto del proyecto en el que se me ha quemado el cerebro jajaj

Comment: ¿No has avanzado nada aún? Sube algo de lo que tengas, para ver el avance.

Comment: No importa que esté *sucio*

Comment: Por el momento está parado hasta que el cliente confirme, pero hoy tocaré un poco más y cuelgo aquí el resultado de lo que lleve.

Comment: encontré esta solución que supuestamente me da el pixel en el que está la coordenada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646691/marking-google-static-maps-via-google-places-api

Ahora.. yo lo tengo en un quad y el marcador tiene que moverse por local. No sé si funcionará.